# Verification of ID tokens on client side

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I'm working on implementing **OAuth 2.0** to a stack of apps I have to reduce the required login credentials. However I am struggeling in understanding the **OpenID Connect** on top of **OAuth 2.0** and how I am supposed to verify the `JWT` token given. Should the public key be supplied inside the actual token so that the client can check the signature?

Also, correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe this token is never sent to the resource server, but acts as a "helping hand" for the client to serve correct output to the user based on information given in the token? If so, is there a set of standards on what type of information each `JWT` should contain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Identity Token is sent following a Successful Token Response which is typically a JWT.

The ID Token validation is described within Section 3.1.3.7. ID Token Validation.

For ID tokens [secured with the RSA or EC signature](https://connect2id.com/blog/how-to-validate-an-openid-connect-id-token) (e.g. RS256), you need the IdP’s public JSON Web Key (JWK) set. It is published as a simple JSON document at an URL which is also advertised in the [OpenID Provider’s metadata]](http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Openid-configuration) in the jwks_uri parameter. You can check out [Google’s JSON Web Key (JWK)](https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs) to see what such as JWK set looks like.

For [ID tokens secured with an HMAC](https://connect2id.com/blog/how-to-validate-an-openid-connect-id-token) (e.g. HS256) you use the client_secret to perform the validation.